# What is the best dua to make to protect you against the consequences of something you’ve done?

Tags: dua, forgiveness, love, mistake, protection

I’ve made a really bad mistake recently and I’m terrified of the consequences of what’s going to happen to me. I’ve become severely depressed and the only thing that’s keeping me going is my belief in Allah and Islam. Please can you tell me a dua that’ll help me through this, one that’ll protect me from the consequences of this awful mistake I made that has ruined my life ,one that’ll help restore my peace of mind and one that’ll ensure everything is ok. I am genuine in my repentance for all the wrongdoings I’ve committed. Please help me I don’t think I’m going to recover from this.

ashadu an la ilaha illa'llah wa ashadu anna muhammadan abduhu wa rasululu

lā ʾilāha ʾillā-llāh, muḥammadur-rasūlu-llāh

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that Allah's forgiveness is greatest than our sin(than all thing).

This dua is helpful to avoid depression, bad thoughts, waswas
**Rabbighfir Warham Wa Anta Khairur Rahemeen** This dua is mentioned in surah Al-Mu'minun(118 verse)

If mistake repeats again, that is not mistake, that is sin.
Scholars said that "We are protected from sins with Duha/Chasht namaz"

The time of Duha begins after the sun fully rises and it ends approximately some minutes before Dhuhr prayer. The most preferred time for Duha prayer is at the hottest part of the day, when the sun has reached its zenith (its highest point), and this is approximately halfway between sunrise and Dhuhr prayer.
You can pray this namaz from 2 rakats til 8 rakats.